# When using the jar file xmlparserv2.jar, transforming a doesn't work when the file path has whitespace. How can i fix this?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, transformer-model

Normally when using ...

```
Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(); 
t.transform(source,result);
```

(without the xmlparserv2.jar file) a File Not Found Exception looks like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\username\nonExistentFile.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

when you include the xmlparserv2.jar, the Exception turns to this

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\username\existingFile.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

The file is actually there (the transform method finds it when i dont include the jar)  but when i include the jar, the transform method cant find it due to the %20 that is inserted for whitespace. Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, should have included more code... the answer was in the Result Object i was passing in.

originally it looked like this

```
File f = new File(filePath);
Result result = new StreamResult(f);
```

changed to this..

```
File f = new File(filePath);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(); 
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
result.setOutputStream(fos);
```